# Vuex – Use "this" keyword in state to access method in child component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm working with Vue (+ Vuetify) and Vuex. In store > state i have a nested object. Mapping it in the child component works as expected, but within the object i'm trying to access a method in the `child component` by `this.row` and `this.hidden`. This results in

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined.

Below is the code from the store and the child component.

```js
// store.js

const state = {
    myValue: {
        radioRequesttype: "New Registration",
        numberInfo: [{ sNumber: '' }]
    },
    mySchema: {
        radioRequesttype: {
            type: "radio",
            row: this.row,
            options: ["New Registration", "Re-registration"]
        },
        sNumberInfo: {
            hidden: this.hidden,
            type: "array",
            flex: 12,

            schema: {
                sNumber: {
                    type: "text",
                    label: "ID",
                    hint: "by re-registration only",
                    flex: 12
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```js
// childcomponent.vue

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters ([
        'myValue',
        'mySchema'
    ]),
    row() {
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(val) {
      update(val);

      let { key, value } = val;

      if (key === "radioRequesttype")
        this.mySchema.sNumberInfo.hidden = value !== "Re-registration";
    },
      ...mapActions ([
          'updateMyValue'
      ])
  }
```

Comment: You should use getters and not try to access the model directly.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, but I already tried that. It makes no difference to the mapGetters helper.

Comment: you need to console.log(this) and see what you have there, likely you are not asking for the correct path, you can also just insert a breakpoint.

Comment: @Michael console logs 'undefined'

Comment: what logs as undefined? your `this`? or something else?

Comment: Yes. 'this' logs as undefined

Comment: `this` is undefined? At what point in your code are you calling `console.log(this)`?

Comment: As it is currently written, your `const state` is not properly defined. `state` is an object, yet, you call `this.row` and `this.hidden`. Is `state` your initial state? On what basis (for _row_ and _hidden_) do you want to initialize your state?